# delete an subarray from an numpy array or replace that subarray elements with 0

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array 'a' and i am creating a subarray with selecting certain row and columns, and calling it an array 'b'. How am i suppose to delete or replace those elements in 'a' which is same as elements in 'b'?

```
def seat():
    print("select your seat")
    import numpy as np
    a = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)
    print(a)
    l1=input("enter row number:")
    l1=int(l1)
    l=l1-1
    n1=input("enter the from column number:")
    n1=int(n1)
    n=n1-1
    p1=input("enter the to column number:")
    p1=int(p1)
    p=p1+1
    b=a[l:, n:p]
    k=b.size
    print("you have booked "+str(k)+"tickets")

    for element in b.flat:
        print("your ticket numbers are:"+ str(element))



    if a.size==0:
        print("there are no tickets left")
    return k;
```

Comment: images are not acceptable. provide your code in text.

Comment: Actually stackoverflow is not allowing me to add image as i have reputation less than 10.

Comment: then copy paste your code using proper formatting.

Comment: In your sample code create the inputs - `a`, `b` and row/column indices.  And show the desired output.  There's a `delete` function.  Indexed assignment may also work.  And the `place` that you tried may also work, though I'm not real familiar with its syntax and function.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar done. check.

Comment: I tried delete but its not working in my case somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code, and a room for improvements.
An issue I see is you probably want:

```
b=a[l, n:p]
```

instead of

```
b=a[l:, n:p]
```

Well that is, if my assumption is correct about what you want to achieve (which you can be clearer about in the question).

Other improvements are like importing at the module level, restricting contents of a function to one logical task/goal, better naming conventions etc. You can get better suggestions at [codereview stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Now, if you want to update your original array `a` with booked tickets, you can do:

```
a[l, n:p] = -1  # -1 here signifies an unavailable seat.
```

And then check if a seat is available or not by checking for -1 value.

Answer (score 0):

I know this should be a comment and not an answer, but I don't have enough rep for adding a comment.

```
b=a[l:, n:p]
```

seems wrong to me, as @0xc0de has pointed out, it should be that way.